# Effect of AC coupling on DC signals

Tags: filter

I am currently trying to amplify a very small AC signal that is riding on a high DC offset.  In order to amplify the signal (using a simple op amp circuit), I obviously need to remove the DC offset to avoid saturating the op amp.  Currently, I am using a series capacitor to block the DC.  So the signal input is coupled to the op amp input terminal with a single series capacitor.

My question is this:  how does this affect the DC component of the signal?  Do I need to add a shunt resistor ground to allow the DC component to pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **must** have a resistor (or inductor etc. ) from the op-amp input to ground, a reference, the output etc., in order to provide a DC path for the op-amp input bias current, otherwise the op-amp will saturate. The feedback resistor can provide this path if it is an inverting amplifier.

If you don't care about the DC value of the signal you can ignore it- provided it changes slowly enough that the AC coupling does not let an undue amount through.

Comment: I am using an inverting amp, so I do have feedback. What happens the the dc that doesn't go through the capacitor? Does it get reflected?

Comment: @crocboy only ac signals can be reflected.

Comment: The output assumes an average value of about zero, and ignores any non-zero average input. So if your signal is a 0V/50mV square wave on top of 5V and you have a gain of -100, you'll end up with a -2.5V/+2.5V square wave at the output.